# Trying to ssh to RPi 3 model B - Connection refused

Tags: raspbian, ssh, headless

I want to use my RPi 3 completely headless with wifi using Raspbian - I don't have neither a USB keyboard nor a monitor. I modified the following two files on the ext4 partition of my SD card.

The content of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
  ssid="XXXX"
  psk="YYYY"
}
```

I add the the following lines to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.200/22
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

And finally I added an empty `ssh` file to the `boot` partition. I've tried to ping the RPi and it seems to be online:

```
PING 192.168.0.200 (192.168.0.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.200: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=67.4 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.200: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=5.59 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.200: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=8.87 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.200: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=9.06 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.200: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=6.35 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.200: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=6.65 ms
--- 192.168.0.200 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.595/17.337/67.491/22.466 ms
```

But the command `ssh pi@192.168.0.200` gives me an error:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.200 port 22: Connection refused
```

Do you have any idea why I can't ssh into my RPi?

Comment: Did you enable SSH? It's disabled by default.

Comment: I'm aware of that SSH is disabled by default. I read on many sites that it is possible to enable SSH by creating a file ssh without any file extensions in the boot directory. Is that possible that the SSH is still disabled?

Comment: Did you really create the `ssh` file in the boot partition or accidentally in the boot folder on the other partition?

Comment: Connection refused has three possible causes: 1. Wrong IP address, 2. Right IP address, wrong port. 3. Right IP address, right port, listener not listening. Three things to check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is simply that port 22 is not listening.

First, fix your static IP address in dhcpcd.conf by removing the "/22" - you actually have a "/24" address which means your netmask is 255.255.255.0

Then go into

```
raspi-config
```

and turn on SSH.  It will ask you to reboot.

At that point it will allow you to either ssh from another Linux box or use PuTTY.

Tidbit:  In your `ssh` command you can add "pi@" to the IP address if you are already logged in with a different name on your Linux box.  If you are already logged in as `pi` then it is not necessary.

Comment: If you want to go truly headless, then be sure to  sudo apt-get install xrdp - then you will be able to use Remmina (Linux) or Microsoft Remote Desktop (Windows) to get a full GUI interface.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I cannot turn on SSH with `rasp-config` command, because I don't have a USB keyboard. I read on many sites that it is possible to enable SSH by creating a new file called `ssh` in the boot partition without any file extension.
I removed "\22" from `dhcpcd.conf` but I still get the same "Connection refused" error message.

Comment: Good that you removed the /22.  Take a look at this and you will see that you really will need a keyboard to accomplish this:  https://roughlea.wordpress.com/raspberry-pi-experiences/configuring-the-raspberry-pi-as-an-ssh-server/

Comment: For what it's worth, I found a link that seems to confirm that "create a file" concept.  It needs to be called ssh (lower case) and put into the directory /Volumes/Boot according to this source (which I do not recognize as being authoritative):  https://howchoo.com/g/ote0ywmzywj/how-to-enable-ssh-on-raspbian-jessie-without-a-screen - but I am dubious.  I don't find that directory in my system.

Comment: Here is an official source, look at section 3.:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

I've created this "ssh" file in my boot partition, so in theory the SSH should be enabled. On the other hand, according to the link above the file is automatically deleted, when Pi enables the SSH - but I still have this file, which means the Pi didn't find the "ssh" file. Ahh... it seems I really need that USB keyboard.

Comment: You need the `pi@` in the `ssh` command as else `ssh` will try to connect with your local user name, which is mostly not what you intent.

Comment: TNX for this comment - I clarified the text to talk to this issue.  I use `pi` as my login name on my Ubuntu boxes but as you point out that should not be assumed.  In fact, I suppose it can't really be assumed that `pi` is the correct name on the Pi, although most people do use it.

Answer (score 0):

Make fresh raspbian install and make a file called "ssh" without any extensions in the boot directory.

This will fix the rest, since raspbian stretch it is not recommended to edit any network files except the dhcpcd.conf. This does include the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Comment: Please differentiate more clearly between a directory and a partition. Placing the file in the `/boot` directory will not help as during boot the boot partition will be mounted over that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Give the details of wifi accordingly eject card place in pi and start.

I am using mac here.

**Mostly your problem will be ssh file having an extension.**

ssh now and try again.